# Parameter issue with operator overload for !=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define an overload for the != operator. My code is as follows. *(Update: outdated code. If one of two article pointers points to NULL, this code will crash.)*

```
bool ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator::operator!=(const ArticleIterator& artit) {
    if (this->article == NULL && artit.article == NULL)
        return false;
    else if (this->article->GetID() != artit.article->GetID())
        return true;
    else if (this->article->GetName() != artit.article->GetName())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on its first line of code, I saw this in the debugger.

> this - 0x22fedc
>
> artit - Unable to create variable object

Apparently the function can't access `artit`, so it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: the call happens here.

```
for (ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator art = cont.Begin(); art != cont.End(); art++) {
    cout << art << "\n";
}
```

Basically, I walk through a list of articles until I encounter the sentinel.

I just tested `cont.End()` right before the for loop:

```
const ArticleIterator& End() const { return *tail; }
```

With *tail*:

```
Name : tail
    Details:0x571900
```

**Edit**: operator++ code is as follows:

```
void ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator::operator++(int i) {
    this->article = this->next->article;
    this->next = this->next->next;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing in for `artit`?

Comment: New question: does it crash on the first iteration? If so, what do `cont.Begin()` and `cont.End()` do? Otherwise, what does `operator ++` do?

Comment: It does not crash on the first iteration, so `cont.Begin()` is not at fault here. I added code for `operator++` to the question.

Comment: @Pieter: It seems as though your `operator !=` might be the one at fault. How is the comparison done? If that is somehow wrong, it could let `art` overshoot the end of the container.

Comment: Aha... I got it. `operator!=` didn't properly ensure that the article pointers were NULL before calling functions on them. But it's still a mystery to me as to why the debugger won't let me access `artit`.

Comment: @Pieter: If `artit` were a pointer, the debugger would have shown its value as `NULL`, but here it's a reference, and you cannot dereference `NULL`, hence the error.

Comment: @Pieter: Also your general structure is a bit strange in that you're mixing iterators with actual content. A `!=` on an iterator is meant to only check if two iterators point to the same location, not if the article contents are the same: that would be accomplished by dereferencing the iterators and doing `*art1 != *art2`.

Comment: `+1` from me for casablanca's last comment. I was about to add the same when I read his. This implementation is wrong.

Comment: @casablanca: thanks for that insight. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *intent* of your code is wrong, but technically you can try this:

```
bool ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator::operator!=(const ArticleIterator& artit) {
    if (article == NULL && artit.article == NULL)
        return false;
    if (article == NULL || artit.article == NULL)
        return true;
    if (article->GetID() != artit.article->GetID())
        return true;
    if (article->GetName() != artit.article->GetName())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

However, even considering only the technical, I'd rather express `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I was just looking back at my code and you're right, I'm doing some weird stuff. I took casablanca's comment to heart and I rewrote the function. Usually I'd write `operator==` and negate the result to create `operator!=`, but my school assignment said specifically that I should create `operator!=`. That's why I didn't create `operator==`.

Comment: Hm. Well, small point, I didn't see that when I copied the code: the functions should be `const` (place a `const` before `{`). Also, while I'm on the general advice track :-), as a general guideline comparison functions are implemented as non-member functions, since that better supports using them with arguments of derived classes, but in this case I don't think that matters. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

bool ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator::operator!=(const ArticleContainer::ArticleIterator& artit);